# Using Regex to parse browser-version from User-Agent-Header 

Tags: java, regex, user-agent

Parsing the user-agent header I need to find out if I am dealing with IE-8 or earlier:

```
<= IE8
```

So the regex should return true in the following cases:

```
(compatible; MSIE 8.0;...)
(compatible; MSIE 7.0;...)
etc.
```

The following should yield false:

```
(compatible; MSIE 9.0;...)
```

This following regex does not work:

```
"MSIE [6-8]\."
```

Comment: This works for me: "(?i).*MSIE [5-8]\..*"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your pattern should work if you escape the backslash, or did you mean JavaScript?. (in which case it should work)

```
"(?i)MSIE\\s+[5-8]\\.\\d+"
```

Explanation:

- `(?i)`   makes the match case insensitive
- `MSIE`   matches the string MSIE
- `\\s+`    one or more spaces
- `[5-8]`  matches digits 5 to 8
- `\\.`     match a dot
- `\\d+`    one or more digits

Comment: It still does not work if I use java.regex (with Scala): 
val ieMatcher = """(?i)MSIE\\s+[5-8]\\.\\d+""".r.pattern
def isIE(str: String) = ieMatcher.matcher(str).matches()

Answer (score 0):

You can use character groups to match versions, f.i. `[678]\.0`.